# Where can I get bilingual dictionary for my application?

Tags: dictionary, localization, linguistics

I'm wondering if there is a place where I can get a bilingual dictionary in open format for my program.
So far I'd like to have just few language pairs: eng-esp, eng-frn, ger-esp, let's say.
I googled and lurked without success so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done translation for an application using BabelFish and it came out ok, especially when you keep captions and messages short. To display different languages I used '[Chilkat's Charset](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/ChilkatCharset.asp)' to render the different languages. I kept all the language translations in an excel file, good thing because customers have added to this language collection for us. The program has all the translations in text files that it uses to populate captions and messages prompts.

Comment: Well, I need to create sort of dictionary not just translate the program interface. Sorry if the original question is unclear...
I.e. I need kind of raw material for dictionary: words, pronunciation in IPA for words, etc.

Comment: Its not possible, for each word in English there isn't a perfect equivilent in say Spanish or French... your best bet would be to tap into the Google API - to get the closest 'pair'. Never the less your still going to need a component like Chilkats Charset to render other languages and to get the IPA stuff may I recommend using a Speech API, eg SAPI

Answer (score 0):

Would a google translate API work?: http://code.google.com/apis/language/